# How can I download image without leaving page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have written servlet which actually writes bytes of an image into the response. I am able download the image by submitting form with action get or post to servlet. But how can I request this servlet without leaving the page?

I tried `jQuery.get("http://localhost:8080/mydownloadservlet")`. Request is getting received in servlet but image is not getting download. Same is working with form submit.

Thanks,
Amit Patel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following worked.

Created hidden iframe.

```
<iframe src="" id="hiddenFrm" style="display:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and using jquery downloaded the image by setting src of hidden frame as follows.

```
function download(url){
    jQuery("#hiddenFrm").attr("src",url);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header to the servlet response. This way the client is forced to pop a *Save As* dialogue.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.gif");
```

Do this *before* writing any byte to the response. You don't need any JavaScript in the client side for this. Just a link or a form pointing to the servlet. The client won't leave the page because the content disposition is not set to `inline`.

You're however still dependent on the client's default configuration whether there's a default action associated with the `Content-Type` of the attachment which will be executed immediately instead of *Save As*. In Firefox for example, this is configureable by *Tools > Options > Applications*. You can't control this from the server side on, but you shouldn't worry about this. The client decided itself to have it so.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to set the HTTP headers correctly:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mypic.jpg
```

2) You need to navigate to that page, not do  `jQuery.get`, but

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/mydownloadservlet">Download pic</a>
```

or in javascript

```
window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/mydownloadservlet';
```

If everything goes according plan, you should actually leave the page.